# In pandas, how can I drop all of the rows in a dataframe that don't contain a specific column value in another dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, parquet

I have two dataframes:

One is a decently large dataset of a million or so records.  This df contains user information including a "list_id" that they're associated with.

The next dataframe is simply a single column of all of the "list" IDs that we want to keep in dataframe #1.  There are about 1000 of these IDs in this dataframe (#2).

The end goal is to drop every single row in dataframe #1 if the ID next that user is not contained in dataframe #2.

What I've tried so far is to iterate on the rows in dataframe #1 in a for loop with a secondary for loop iterating on the IDs in dataframe #2.  If it doesn't the first for loop doesn't find the ID in dataframe #2, it drops the row.  Here's what I've tried:

df1:

| user_id | list_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 234235 |
| 4567 | 754654 |
| 9012 | 345445 |

df2:

| list_ids |
| --- |
| 234235 |
| 754654 |
| 123456 |

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['list_id'] not in df2['list_ids']:
        #Remove user if not associated to list
        df1.drop(index=index, inplace=True)
```

The biggest problem with this is how large the data set is.  This took about 8 hours to run, only to find out that it actually dropped every single row in df1.  I feel like this is not the best approach to this problem and there's got to be a more "pandas-like" way to solve this issue.  If any more information is needed, I'd be happy to add it!

Comment: `df1.loc[df1['list_id'].isin(df2['list_ids'].tolist())]`